# What is the point of having continuity from below and above?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Continuity from below is defined as

> If $\{E_j\}_1^\infty \subset \mathcal{M}$ and $E_1 \subset E_2 \subset
> > ...$ , then $\mu(\bigcup_1^\infty E_j) = \lim_{j\rightarrow \infty}
> > \mu(E_j)$

There is a corresonding definition for continuity from above.

I am just starting on measure theory and is having a hard time figuring out why we have the above property. What is the point of having this property in a measure space? In probability measure space, why is it important? I am particularly looking for an intuitive reasoning for having this property.

Comment: I thought this follows from the definition of a measure. When you say "what is the point of having this property", it makes it seem like you think it is part of the definition of a measure.

Comment: @mathworker21 maybe i should say how should i interpret this property intuitively?

Comment: You can think about it geometrically. In $\mathbb{R}^2$ for example. $E_1$ is some region, $E_2$ is a region containing it, $E_3$ is a region containing $E_2$, etc. And $\cup_j E_j$ is the union of these regions. Then we expect the area of the $E_n$'s to approach the area of the total region $\cup_j E_j$.

Comment: It might be easier, psychologically, to fix the total region first. Then what continuity from below is saying is that no matter how you build this total region up from smaller regions, the areas will increase to that of the total region.

Comment: @Dzoooks Can you specify an example that shows that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n = A$ does not imply $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu(A_n) = \mu(A)$?

Comment: @user136266 In a finite measure space, when $\lim A_n=A$, by looking at $\lim \inf A_n$ and $\lim \sup A_n$ we see that $\lim \mu(A_n) = \mu(A).$  For infinite spaces, even $\sigma$-finte, we do not necessarily have continuity from above, e.g. $A_n=[n,\infty)$.